# Check if the function is differentiable or not

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

> Consider $f: \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$, $$f(x, y) = \begin{cases}\frac{xy^2}{x^2 + 2y^2} & (x, y) \ne (0,0)\\0 & (x, y) = (0,0)\end{cases}$$
>
> Where is $f(x, y)$ differentiable over its domain?

I am considering $(0, 0)$ as a point, but I am not sure how to go about proving it (or disproving)

Comment: What does it mean for $f$ to be differentiable at $(0,0)$?

Comment: @Jason, $\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} \frac{|R(x, y)|}{||(x, y) - (0,0)||} = 0$, where $R$ is the $f(x) - L(x)$ around $(0,0)$ with $L(x)$ being the linear approx.

Comment: if both numerator and denominator are homogeneous (these are) we can get good information by switching to polar coordinates. For diff

Comment: First show that the partial derivatives are both zero at the origin. Then, if the function were differentiable at the origin, all of its directional derivatives would need to be zero. (This is a necessary, but not sufficient, condition.) If you check the directional derivative along the line $y = x$, you'll see that it exists, but it isn't zero.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the definition of partial derivatives to compute
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x,0)-f(0,0)}{x-0}=0$$ and $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{f(0,y)-f(0,0)}{y-0}=0.$$
Then to check differentiability
\begin{align}\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{f(x,y)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)(x-0)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)(y-0)}{\sqrt{(x-0)^2+(y-0)^2}}\\
=\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{xy^2}{(x^2+2y^2)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}.
\end{align}
To prove differentiability you need to check if the limit exists and is zero. In this case the limit does not exist. Hint: use restrictions, such that $y=x$ or $y=0$,

Comment: A question, why cant I claim partial derivative at (0, 0) is $0$ from the function, which is defined as $0$ as $(0,0)$?

Comment: just because a function is zero at one point does not mean its partial derivatives are zero. Take $f(x,y)=x$. Then $f(0,0)=0$ but $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=1$.

Comment: I meant, cant we differentiate AT the point? Ie. $\partial f/ \partial x = \partial 0 / \partial x$?

Comment: No. You can use the fact that $f(x,0)=0$ for all $x$ and then differentiate with respect to $x$. Just at one point would not be enough. Take $f(x,y)=x$ for $x\ne 0$ and $f(0,0)=0$. Then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=1\ne \frac{\partial 0}{\partial x}(0,0)=0$

Answer (score 4):

The partial derivatives at $(0,0)$ are both $0$. Hence, $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ if and only if the following limit exits:

$$\lim_{(h,k)\to(0,0)} \frac{f(h,k)}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}$$

This limit obviously doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

There are directional derivatives in every direction. These are found immediately in polar when both numerator and denominator are homogeneous, using
$$ r \frac{\cos \theta \sin^2 \theta}{ \cos^2 \theta + 2 \sin^2 \theta}  $$
so that the directional derivative in (unit) direction $\theta$ is
$$  \frac{\cos \theta \sin^2 \theta}{ \cos^2 \theta + 2 \sin^2 \theta}  $$
Now, writing this back in cartesian coordinates, does this indicate a linear function of the direction (not necessarily unit)? The answer is no, as this is zero on the axes, when $\theta $ is a multiple of $\pi/2,$ but nonzero elsewhere. If the thing were linear, we would always get zero.